# Finding the greatest common divisor of two numbers in Bash

Tags: bash, shell, greatest-common-divisor

I am coding a program that computes the GCD of two numbers. My problem happens in some input cases:

```
GCD (88, 100) = 4
```

But my program returns an empty space (like it couldn't get the `$gcd`), but I haven't really got to the exact problem in my code yet.

```
#!/bin/bash

while true; do
    read a b
    gcd=$a
    if [ $b -lt $gcd ]; then
        gcd=$b
    fi
    while [ $gcd -ne 0 ]; do
        x=`expr $a % $gcd`
        y=`expr $b % $gcd`
        if [ $x -eq 0 -a $y -eq 0 ]; then
            echo "GCD ($a, $b) = $gcd"
        break
        fi
    done
done
```

Comment: Your program only ever sets `$gcd` to `$a` or `$b` and it doesn't update it inside the inner loop.

Comment: Unrelated to the actual problem: ```x=`expr $a % $gcd` ``` is unnecessarily complicated (and the backticks for subshells are outdated). You could write `((x = a % gcd))` instead.

Comment: With `expr`, backticks, no [[ ]] form tests ,looks like 20 years old script

Answer (score 5):

You could define a function that implements the [Euclidean algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm):

```
gcd() (
    ! (( $1 % $2 )) && echo $2 || gcd $2 $(( $1 % $2 ))
)
```

the function uses the ternary operator `test && cmd1 || cmd2` and recursion (it calls itself). Or define a more readable version of the function:

```
gcd() (
    if (( $1 % $2 == 0)); then
        echo $2
     else
        gcd $2 $(( $1 % $2 ))
    fi
)
```

Test:

```
$ gcd 88 100
4
```

Comment: `[ $(( $1 % $2 )) -eq 0 ] &&` in bash just `(( $1 % $2 == 0 )) && `. The `$(echo $(( $1 % $2 )))` is a useless use of `echo`, just `$(( $1 % $2 ))`.